# What's the legal syntax to define nested template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following nested template

```
class A {
    template <typename T> class B {
        template <typename U> void foo(U arg);
    };
};
```

I am trying to define the nested template like so:

```
template <typename T, typename U> void
A::B<T>::foo(U arg) {...}
```

But am getting `declaration is incompatible with function template` error. What's the legal syntax to do so?

Comment: You almost might as well just define it right there. It can't go in a separate file.

Comment: @chris: just because it cant be in a separate translation unit doesn't mean it cant be in a different file.  Even if it did have to be in the same file, you can still separate implementation from interface.

Comment: @MooingDuck, True, files != TUs. I was thinking more along the lines of defining it generically in a linked-to file. And I, myself, do like defining templates outside of the class definition, which is why I said almost. I figured the OP would be going for the first point, where it will fail.

Comment: I frequently use .inl files to hold my template function definitions, so that I don't have to pollute the interface declaration with them.  It's a little bit funky in its syntax, because you have to #include the .inl file at the end of the header file (below the class declaration), but it makes the code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to separate the template declarations:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
void
A::B<T>::foo(U arg) { … }
```

Comment: I tried that but doesn't seem to work either - the compiler seems to be confusing `T` with `U`. I call `arg.UMember()` in `foo`, but the compiler complains `A::B<T> has no member UMember`

Comment: Empty braces calling default constructors instead of initializer-list constructors and this. Today is an exceptionally good day for learning.

Comment: @MiloChen: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4db49730dd7df44b6f01839277cc6c4f-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba.  Do you have the `T` template before the `U` template?  [They have to be in the right order.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0b98f6449a84341a2111b33f48a3536e-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: Thanks - must still be additional bugs elsewhere. Damn.

Comment: Now I've got a bizarre error `unable to match function definition to an existing declaration: definition "void A::B<T>::foo(U &)"; existing declarations "void A::B<T>::foo(U &)"` (my `U` is passed by reference btw). Any hints you could give?